# use of laravel 5.3 dashboard

Tags: laravel-5.3, dashboard

I want to create a laravel 5.3 project. i am early in laravel. i want to use laravel dashboard. i use [this link](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Laralum). view of that dashboard is same it:

[image]

but when i install that file, i see this view:
[image]

Why my dashboard is not same that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this link](https://almsaeedstudio.com/blog/integrate-adminlte-with-laravel). That learn step by step for install and use a laravel dashboard.